# Removing all tab characters from Pandas DataFrame for Specific Column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove all tab characters in a Pandas DataFrame for a specific column.

Here's what I have tried so far but have not had much success:

```
df[insert column name here]= df[insert column name here].replace("\t"," ")
```

I was wondering if anyone can help me out.

Note: I am **not** looking to replace the tabs with a space in the column heading. I want to replace the tabs in the **actual cells** that contain unstructured text.

Comment: this question is a dupe. Either use `df['col'].str.replace("\t"," ")` or `df['col'].replace("\t"," ", regex=True)`